# Can I change JSON property in OData result?

Tags: c#, json, odata

I created a model to use with OData but, in JSON output, I want to change the properties' name.

This is my model:

```
public partial class Z_TESTE_DATA
{
    [Key]
    public decimal DATA_ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime DATA_DATE { get; set; }

    public string DATA_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

And, instead of DATA_ID, DATA_DATE and DATA_NAME, I want to change, for example, to DATA_ID_2, DATA_DATE_2 and DATA_NAME_2. Can I do that?

Comment: Are you using something like JSON.net to convert your model to JSON?

Comment: No. OData converts automatically data to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData version 4 or higher supports property aliasing. You can try adding the dataMember attribute to your properties to give them alternative names e.g.

```
public partial class Z_TESTE_DATA
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember(Name = "DATA_ID_2")]
    public decimal DATA_ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "DATA_DATE_2")]
    public DateTime DATA_DATE { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "DATA_NAME_2")]
    public string DATA_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

The reverse would also be possible;

```
public partial class Z_TESTE_DATA
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember(Name = "DATA_ID")]
    public decimal DATA_ID_2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "DATA_DATE")]
    public DateTime DATA_DATE_2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "DATA_NAME")]
    public string DATA_NAME_2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but is not working. My application shows this error:  `The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'DATA_DATE' on type 'DSVtoJSON.Models.Models.DbModels.Z_TESTE_DATA'.`

Comment: I'm sure you've checked but are you using OData v4 or higher?

Comment: I'm using System.Web.OData and I think that is v4. In my model, I have to reference a particular library?

Comment: You can check your version by looking at the installed packages in NUGet

Comment: I am using OData v4 and It works if I implement your first suggestion and if query in URL would have the names that appear in DataMember.